# Fixing "stretched" XPage extension library dialog box in IE?

Tags: xpages

When a dialog box is displayed in IE, it appears to stretch to the right.  I understand there might be a temporary fix for this?   Can anyone provide that fix?

Comment: Can you provide some example code? Are you running IE in Compatibility Mode (just a guess)?

Comment: Which IE version is used? I have seen some problems with dialogs in IE7 because of a wrong CSS attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We encountered the same problem and solved it by specifying the width of the dialog. This prevents it from stretching to the right. In addition, don't forget to close your Firebug console, if your dialog contains a fair amount of content, it distorts the dialog as well.

To reproduce the effect you can copy/paste the code below, add a couple of paragraphs of text to it and remove the specified width from the dialog.

```
<xp:button value="Show Dialog" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.openDialog("#{id:dialog1}");]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>

<xe:dialog id="dialog1" title="Dialog title" style="width:800px;">
    <xe:dialogContent>
        <p>Lorem ipsum ... </p>
    </xe:dialogContent>
    <xe:dialogButtonBar>
        <xp:button value="Ok" id="button1" styleClass="lotusFormButton">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.closeDialog('#{id:dialog1}')]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
        <xp:link id="link1" text="Cancel" styleClass="lotusAction">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.closeDialog('#{id:dialog1}')]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:link>
    </xe:dialogButtonBar>
</xe:dialog>
```