# Fixing "stretched" XPage extension library Name Picker in IE?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Dalie came up with a great solution to stop the "stretched" to the right dialog boxes when they appear in IE.

[Fixing "stretched" XPage extension library dialog box in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456050/fixing-stretched-xpage-extension-library-dialog-box-in-ie)

Dalie's solution was to set the width of the dialog box.  This worked great.   But now I am having the same issue with the extension library Name Picker.  It has a width property which I set but does not seem to solve the problem.

To review, basically in IE dialog boxes are "stretched"  all the way over to the right border of the dialog box.  No matter where you move the dialog box the right side stays anchored in place.

Any solution to this issue?

Comment: It seems to be related to IE displaying the page in compatibility mode. I see the same with IE8 where the page is rendered in IE7 Standards mode. If I change to IE8 Standards mode, it renders as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try forcing IE not to use compatibility mode by setting the X-UA-Compatible header to IE=8 (or even IE=Edge):

```
<xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:  if (context.getUserAgent().isIE()) {
    var response = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    response.setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=8");
  }}]]>
</xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
```

Comment: Thanks that did it.  At least till IE changes something again. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am using oneuiv2.1. When I do above change, width of lotusContent which is supposed to be 100%, changes to 30 or 40%. If I use oneuiv2 it works fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: I use the above trick for oneuiv2.1 with no problems. Please ask a question with details on your issue and tag it xpages.