# IE Compatibility mode creates issues with XPages DateTimePicker

Tags: xpages

Per Henrik suggested a fix for the strange stretched dialog problems in IE with xPage extensions.

[Fixing "stretched" XPage extension library Name Picker in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606922/fixing-stretched-xpage-extension-library-name-picker-in-ie)

This worked great and fixed the problem.  But it creates an issue with the DateTimePicker.  With compatibility mode in place the calendar for the DateTimePicker displays but is immediately closed.  I have put together a demo here:

```
 <xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
    <![CDATA[#{javascript:  if (context.getUserAgent().isIE()) {
    var response = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    response.setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=8");
}}]]>
</xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>




<xp:inputText id="inputText1">
    <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper1"></xp:dateTimeHelper>
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime type="date"></xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply used the dojo date picker and it seemed to work for me. No reason to get themes involved.

Answer (score 3):

I have stumbled into the exact same problem. My fix is inspired by [a blog post by Paul 
Withers on the subject](http://www.intec.co.uk/xpages-date-picker-my-preference/) and involves using the Dojo DateTextBox and TimeTextBox for IE.

I use standard date fields:

```
<xp:inputText id="FejlDato" value="#{document.FejlDato}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime type="date"></xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
    <xp:dateTimeHelper></xp:dateTimeHelper>
</xp:inputText>
```

And add a theme id to time fields in order to target them in a theme:

```
<xp:inputText id="FejlTid" value="#{document.FejlTid}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime type="time"></xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
    <xp:this.themeId><![CDATA[${javascript:if (context.getUserAgent().isIE()) { "InputField.TimePicker" }}]]></xp:this.themeId>
    <xp:dateTimeHelper></xp:dateTimeHelper>
</xp:inputText>
```

I then use the following in a theme to use dijit.form.DateTextBox and dijit.form.TimeTextBox for IE instead of the standard XPages date and time pickers:

```
<!-- DatePicker for IE8 and IE9 -->
<resources>
    <dojoModule rendered="#{javascript:context.getUserAgent().isIE()}">
        <name>dijit.form.DateTextBox</name>
     </dojoModule>
     <dojoModule rendered="#{javascript:context.getUserAgent().isIE()}">
        <name>dijit.form.TimeTextBox</name>
     </dojoModule>
</resources>
<control>
    <name>InputField.DateTimePicker</name>
    <property>
        <name>dojoType</name>
        <value>#{javascript:context.getUserAgent().isIE()?'dijit.form.DateTextBox':''}</value> 
    </property>
</control>
<control>
    <name>InputField.TimePicker</name>
    <property>
        <name>dojoType</name>
        <value>#{javascript:context.getUserAgent().isIE()?'dijit.form.TimeTextBox':''}</value> 
    </property>
</control>
```

Comment: I have used a similar work-around based on Paul's suggestion in the past. The theme approach is a nice idea.

Comment: I simply used the dojo date picker and it seemed to work for me.   No reason to get themes involved.

Comment: Great to hear that it works for you. Remember to accept answers to your questions :-)

Answer (score 1):

IE9 works fine, but if you turn on compatibility mode it doesn't... IE Science fiction