# XPages Extension Library Calendar (iNotes Calendar) doesn't work with Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am having problems with iNotes Calendar on my Intern Explorer (ver 11.0). I have tested it successfully on Firefox and Chrome. I guess it is a bug, but I just need to confirm this and is there any way around. Here is a small piece of code, just to describe the problem:

```
//tesCalendar.xsp    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
        xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
        <xe:calendarView id="calendarView1">
            <xe:this.onNewEntry><![CDATA[
    var calDate = calendar.getDate();
    alert(calDate);]]></xe:this.onNewEntry>
        </xe:calendarView></xp:view>
```

The problem would be generated when you try to create a new entry (double click on any calendar date). It shows a wrong date, purely randomly. I am using an extension library dated 15-04-2013. Is it probably fixed in the later version?

Any help would really be appreciated.

Edit 1: I tried adding the compatibility mode as suggested by Paul in the comment. But with no luck :(.  I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606922/fixing-stretched-xpage-extension-library-name-picker-in-ie) question on stack overflow for adding compatibility mode.Here is what I added to my above code.

```
<xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:  if (context.getUserAgent().isIE()) {
    var response = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    response.setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=8");
  }}]]>
</xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
```

Edit 2: I installed the latest version of Extension Library dated 19-06-2014. But still the same problem. When you create a new event it just displays date randomly. However, it works great with firefox and chrome.

Comment: Is this in compatibility mode or not? That may change the behaviour, though I'm not sure how feasible it is for your app to change the document mode.

Comment: I have just updated the code with compatibility mode thing with no success. Also, I am not sure, what you mean by document mode in this context. Can you just describe it a bit more?

Comment: You can change the document mode but can't really switch compatibility mode on or off. See http://www.intec.co.uk/compatibility-mode-what-any-xpages-or-web-developer-needs-to-know/. It's basically what you've done.

Comment: So, what is the solution here? Just accept the bug and ask customers to not use the application in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a problem for just IE11 or all versions of IE. It sounds like it's a bug, possibly this one http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Extension%20Library/discussions/55C1A4828FCB113986257B1D000DF980. You may need to check readme files for when that was fixed.

Comment: I will try to update my extension library today and try out with the lower version of IE to find out the same and revert on this soon. Thanks a lot for the direction :)

Comment: So, well, I installed the latest version of extension library (19-06-2014) and still the same problem :(

Comment: It's worth raising a defect in the Extension Library project. If you can reproduce it in a very basic XPage, completely standalone, it will help identify the cause.

Comment: Yea, great, I will do it soon..I have just created an new application with only one XPage to test it. And I would just post the same standalone code I posted here..Thanks a lot..I mark it as the correct answer now :)